# ELANtech touchpad not detected anymore on Ubuntu 15

Tags: touchpad, 15.04, elantech

I'm having trouble with my touchpad with Ubuntu 15.

When running it off the usb drive the touchpad didn't work already.
I rebooted and went straight to the setup and there it worked no problem.

Then the touchpad worked for a while until it spontaneously didn't anymore (after a reboot).
Googled a bit and found something about the `touchpad indicator`. It doesn't actually seem to work on Ubuntu 15. At least I see no indicator.
Even so after installing that and rebooting the touchpad was recognized once again.

Then it worked for a while again until it spontaneously didn't anymore (after a reboot), which is now. Checked xinput and `/proc/bus/input/devices` and it's not even detected unfortunately.

Any idea what the problem might be and how it can be that it works for a bit and then Ubuntu decides to forget about it all of a sudden? It works just fine on Windows.

Here's some info:

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
N: Name="Sleep Button"
N: Name="Power Button"
N: Name="Lid Switch"
N: Name="Power Button"
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
N: Name="Video Bus"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
N: Name="ELAN Touchscreen"
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse"
N: Name="MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse"
N: Name="PC Cam"
```

Note that the laptop does have a touchscreen and it works.
The MOSART mouse is a bluetooth mouse I use to be able to point at things without having to touch the screen.

`xinput --list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PC Cam                                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux devtop 3.19.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 29 10:10:47 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


dmesg | grep pnp
[    0.211331] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.211600] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.218056] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.218106] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD0414 PNP0f03 (active)
[    0.219325] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices
```

Don't know what kind of laptop it is. It's some sort of custom-built one. I do know that the touchpad is from elantech, though.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i8042.kbdreset=1` kernel boot parameter fixed my problem.
To shamelessly copy @Pilot6's instructions:

---

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

And add there to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` `i8042.kbdreset=1`.

It should look like

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.kbdreset=1"`

Then save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

With this the touchpad will work after a reboot and will continue to do so after rebooting again.

Comment: Worked for me on a Gigabyte P37W v5 !

Answer (score 1):

`i8042.nomux=1` kernel boot parameter may help.

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

And add there to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` `i8042.nomux=1`.

It should look like

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux=1"`

Then save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

It may work after reboot.

Comment: Mh, I just rebooted again after a couple of days when I would just let the laptop sleep and now the mouse is not working anymore again. :( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Machisuji If `kbdreset=1` solved it for you, then write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I have an Elantouchpad also on this Asus UX31E. The default drivers have been working great with it. There is a solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253069) for a Focaltech touchpad.

Comment: OP has Elantech. And the Focaltech solution was made by me :-)))